# Unable to return database query results

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

I'm at the early stages of incorporating a search facility on a website, but I've hit a stumbling block. At the moment, I'm just doing some testing, using jQuery AJAX, but the problem definitely lies in my php:

```
...

$searchq = $_POST['searchq'];
$output = '';

$db = new PDO($dsn, $mysqluser, $mysqlpass, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

function getData($db){
    // Prepare resource query statement
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mod_site_content WHERE alias = ':searchq'");
    // Bind paremeters
    $stmt->bindParam(':searchq', $searchq, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    // Execute query
    $stmt->execute();
    // Grab result
    $output = $stmt->fetchAll();
    // Return output
    done($output);
};

try {
    getData($db);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

function done($out){
    echo $out;
}
```

At the moment I'm just passing the results to console.log() in my AJAX `.done()` method. The above outputs "Array" with nothing in it, regardless of whether I search for something that *should* be there or not.

If I change the above slightly to:

```
function getData($db){
    ...
    $output = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $result = implode($output,"--");
    // Reture output
    done($result);
};
```

I get nothing back whatsoever.

`mod_site_content` looks like this:

```
id | type     | alias
-------------------------
1  | document | home
2  | document | projects
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: where is `$searchq` defined?

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that - see edited.

Comment: column name is alias ?? why?

Comment: The variable is not defined inside the function, this due to variable scope in php! please read about it!

Comment: @zod - It's a Modx CMS table - their structure, not mine.

Comment: are you able to execute that query in sql editor...just to know

Comment: `echo json_encode($out)` and make sure you are expecting a json object on the browser.

Comment: @zod - If I swap out `:searchq` for an entry, yes it works.

Comment: Use your `$db` variable as a global inside your `getData` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mod_site_content WHERE alias = ':searchq'");
```

replace it by this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mod_site_content WHERE alias = :searchq");
```

PDO variable i.e. :searchq shouldn't be surrounded by `'` or else PDO will consider them as strings, your code should be giving an error when you try to bind `searchq`

Additionally notice that I used the `prepare()` not `query()`, you need to prepare the query first, then bind params then execute

third issue, you should pass `$searchq` to your `getData` function

I copied and pasted your code here, and edited, just to clear my head, can you please test it and tell me if it works?

```
$searchq = $_POST['searchq'];
$output = '';

$db = new PDO($dsn, $mysqluser, $mysqlpass, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

function getData($db, $searchq){
    // Prepare resource query statement
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mod_site_content WHERE alias = :searchq");
    // Bind paremeters
    $stmt->bindParam(':searchq', $searchq, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    // Execute query
    $stmt->execute();
    // Grab result
    $output = $stmt->fetchAll();
    // Return output
    done($output);
};

try {
    getData($db, $searchq);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

function done($out){
    if(is_array($out)){
       print_r($out);
    } else {
       echo $out;
    }
}
```

Comment: This still gives an empty array. If I substitute `:searchq` for a string that's definitely in the table it works though.

Comment: oh just noticed you're using `query()` not `prepare()`... check my updated answer @verism

Comment: I appreciate your help, but the result's exactly the same.

Comment: @verism are you echoing the array or using `var_dump` or `print_r`?

Comment: @verism try the updated code, and let me know if it works, just out of curiosity, because I can't see anything else wrong with your code.

Comment: Still nothing... other than the $dsn, $mysqluser and $mysqlpass variables, that's the entire script. It connects fine - I'm not getting any errors - but the response is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58994/discussion-between-codebird-and-verism).

Answer (score 0):

`echo json_encode($out)` and make sure you are expecting a json object on the browser.

No idea offhand why imploding the return value and echoing it out failed to return anything, unless `->fetchAll` doesn't return an actual array according to implode, in which case it should be kicking out an error somewhere...

Comment: My bad - I was making numerous revisions based on comments and lost track of my edits. Sadly it's not the solution.